# Gradle Build Error In Unity with error Could not get unknown property 'unityStreamingAssets'

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
`C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.2.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.2.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.6.4.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"` 
`stderr[`

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\Nik\Downloads\Stu\Temp\gradleOut\launcher\build.gradle' line: 30
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.
  Could not get unknown property 'unityStreamingAssets' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.AaptOptions.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Picked up `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`
]
stdout[

`Configure project :launcher WARNING: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version of the Android Gradle plugin, and will no longer allow you to disable R8. ] exit code: 1`

Answer (score 14):

Add this line to gradle.properties file:

*unityStreamingAssets=.unity3d, google-services-desktop.json, google-services.json, GoogleService-Info.plist*

Fixed it for me :)

Answer (score 4):

As Chris said, you have put this at the bottom of your `gradle.properties` file:

```
unityStreamingAssets=.unity3d, google-services-desktop.json, google-services.json, GoogleService-Info.plist
```

There's a few gotchas though:

**If you don't have/can't find a `gradle.properties` file**:

Build Settings > Player Setttings > (Android Icon) > Publishing Settings

And look for `Custom Gradle Properties Template` - if you see it checked, there's a `.properties` file below it which is equivalent to your gradle.properties.

**If you already have a `unityStreamingAssets=` line**:

You can combine the new line with your old one if you want to keep your old unitStreamingAssets tags; however you must put the line **below** `**ADDITIONAL_PROPERTIES**` or it won't work!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [uaal-example](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/uaal-example/blob/master/docs/android.md) example. One of the steps in the readme is to copy the `gradle.properties` from the android export to your native app as one of those properties defines `unityStreamingAssets`.

> Copy gradle.properties file from exported Unity project root folder to
> native application root folder or create a symlink to make sure that
> this file is always up to date